Integrating ArcGIS world imagery to QGIS
I am trying to integrate ArcGIS world imagery layer into QGIS.
The version of QGIS I use is 3.38.
After following all the steps, the layer 'world imagery' appears on the left side, but taking forever to render. It is not rendering at all even after hours. All I can see is a white black canvas. The same with High resolution layer. The URL I used is https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer
Can anyone suggest what might be the issue and how to resolve this?

I think you have the wrong URL  This one displays for me in QGIS without issue.  Here are the steps to get the correct link in QGIS.
From the link you provided choose the WMTS link.

That takes you to this screen.

Copy the URL.
Open QGIS and use the browser window, and the WMS/WMTS drop down and find your broken link.  Right click to Edit.  This should open the Create a New WMS/WMTS connection dialog box.
Paste the correct URL in the URL area.  Be sure to press the OK button and close the dialog box.

You should now be able to add the WMTS to your QGIS project.


Thank you. Can you please mention the steps you followed? I would like to cross check each step. Also, when I put the URL you shared, it is saying 'connection failed, parsing error'.

OK, I have edited my answer.  If you check the answer as correct I would appreciate it.

Yes, it did work. Thank you so much.
